# jQuery while using find function its children returns the attribute with undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("table.overview-table td.orange.white").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("rowspan") > 0) {
        var childrens = $(this).parent().next("tr").find("*");
        for(x = 0; x < childrens.length; x++) {
            console.log(childrens[x].attr("workerid"));
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table" border=1>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="dark" style="width: 50px;">Tijd</th>
         <th class="dark">Kapper 1</th>
         <th class="dark">Kapper 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="overview_table_td">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">03:15</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0" data-time="03:15:00" workerid="196"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row" class="dark">03:30</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange white" onclick="show_app("4614")" rowspan="2" data-time="03:30:00" workerid="196">test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">03:45</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0" data-time="03:45:00" workerid="196"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

While i m fetching children element's attribute at that time below error is showing

Uncaught TypeError: childrens[x].attr is not a function

Looking for help

Comment: Can you please add Html here too ?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe `$(childrens[x]).attr("workerid")`

Comment: can you add the HTML as well, or a JSFiddle would be even better

Comment: In what circumstance does `$(this).attr("rowspan")` return `"undefined"`?

Comment: Let me do jsfiddle

Comment: @MikaelLennholm _"As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set."_ .- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: i just add code snippet you can check it

Comment: @kosmos @charlietfl `undefined` sure, but `"undefined"`?

Comment: Please check i add code snippet

Comment: i just remove unnecessary code please check now and if anyone have solution of this please help me.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Good eye there 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(childrens[x]).attr("workerid")` instead of 
`childrens[x].attr("worked")`

$(element) Selects the HTML element so that you can you can get/set properties/attributes of that element through jquery.

```
function rowspan_treatment(){
$("table.overview-table td.orange.white").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("rowspan") > 0 && $(this).attr("rowspan") !== "undefined") {
        var childrens = $(this).parent().next("tr").find("*");
        for(x = 0; x < childrens.length; x++) {
            console.log($(childrens[x]).attr("workerid"));
        }
    }
});
}
```

```js
$("table.overview-table td.orange.white").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("rowspan") > 0) {
        var childrens = $(this).parent().next("tr").find("*");
        for(x = 0; x < childrens.length; x++) {
        
            if($(childrens[x]).attr("workerid") != undefined){
            
            console.log($(childrens[x]).attr("workerid"));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table" border=1>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="dark" style="width: 50px;">Tijd</th>
         <th class="dark">Kapper 1</th>
         <th class="dark">Kapper 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="overview_table_td">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">03:15</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0" data-time="03:15:00" workerid="196"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row" class="dark">03:30</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange white" onclick="show_app("4614")" rowspan="2" data-time="03:30:00" workerid="196">test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">03:45</th>
         <td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0" data-time="03:45:00" workerid="196"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "*You should...*" – why? While I, and I'm fairly certain many others, can see and understand, without explaining to the OP you're not really teaching anything. @CarstenLøvboAndersen: the point is that if the solution posted in a comment is correct then that solution cannot be accepted if it remains a comment. If you want the rep points for posting the answer then you should have posted an answer instead of leaving a – transitory – comment.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen On the flip side, what's the point of writing an **answer** in the comments? Proper answers can be accepted and make the question resolved. We want to get as many questions as possible resolved in one way or another (be it properly answered or flagged)